# How can I check if array is full and double/half the size of it?

Tags: c++

This program reads information from a text file, stores it in an array, and performs one of 3 functions. I need to be able to check if the array is full and double the size if it is or half the size if their is a deletion 1/4 of the size of the array. Tried to be brief so if you need more information, let me know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct info{
  char letter;
  string SSN;
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
};

void insertion(int &count, int &validInsertationCount, string &SSN, char &letter, string &firstName, string &lastName, info *list);
void deletion(int &count, int &validDeletionCount, string &SSN, char &letter, string &firstName, string &lastName, info *list);
void retrieval(int &count, int &validRetrievalCount, string &SSN, string &firstName, string &lastName, info *list);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  int arraySize = 1000;
  struct info list[1000];
  fstream input(argv[1]);
  int count = 0;
  int validInsertationCount = 0;
  int validDeletionCount = 0;
  int validRetrievalCount = 0;
  while(!input.eof()){
    input >> list[count].letter >> list[count].SSN >> list[count].firstName >> list[count].lastName;

    if(list[count].letter == 'i'){
      insertion(count, validInsertationCount, list[count].SSN, list[count].letter, list[count].firstName, list[count].lastName, list);
    }
    else if(list[count].letter == 'd'){
      deletion(count, validDeletionCount, list[count].SSN, list[count].letter, list[count].firstName, list[count].lastName, list);
    }
    else if(list[count].letter == 'r'){
      retrieval(count, validRetrievalCount, list[count].SSN, list[count].firstName, list[count].lastName, list);
    }
    count++;
  }
  input.close();

  int numberOfItems = validInsertationCount - validDeletionCount;

  cout << "The Number of Valid Insertation: " << validInsertationCount << endl;
  cout << "The Number of Valid Deletion: " << validDeletionCount << endl;
  cout << "The Number of Valid Retrieval: " << validRetrievalCount << endl;
  cout << "Item Numbers in the array: " << numberOfItems << endl;
  cout << "Array Size is: " << arraySize  << endl;
  //cout << "Time Elapsed: " <<  <<endl;                                                                                                                     
}
void insertion(int &count, int &validInsertationCount, string &SSN, char &letter, string &firstName, string &lastName, info *list){
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if(SSN == list[i].SSN && list[i].letter == 'i'){
      for(int k = i; k < count; k++){
      list[k].SSN = list[k+1].SSN;
      list[k].letter = list[k+1].letter;
      list[k].firstName = list[k+1].firstName;
      list[k].lastName = list[k+1].lastName;
      }
      count--;
      return;
    }
  }
  validInsertationCount++;
  return;
}
void deletion(int &count, int &validDeletionCount, string &SSN, char &letter, string &firstName, string &lastName, info *list){
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if(SSN == list[i].SSN && firstName == list[i].firstName && lastName == list[i].lastName){
      for(int k = i; k < count; k++){
      list[k].SSN = list[k+1].SSN;
      list[k].letter = list[k+1].letter;
      list[k].firstName = list[k+1].firstName;
      list[k].lastName = list[k+1].lastName;
      }
      count--;
      validDeletionCount++;
      return;
    }
  }
}
void retrieval(int &count, int &validRetrievalCount, string &SSN, string &firstName, string &lastName, info *list){
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if(SSN == list[i].SSN && firstName == list[i].firstName && lastName == list[i].lastName){
      validRetrievalCount++;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Arrays have a fixed number of elements, *always*, so an array is always "full". If you want to distinguish between different values in an array you need to define "empty" as a special value. For example, if you have an array of pointers to something, then a null pointer could mean "empty". If you want an "array" that can change size during runtime (increase or decrease) then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg when the array is created, are all the values NULL?

Comment: @ThomasMolloy: Only if you have an array of pointers and if the array has static storage duration or if you explicitly initialised it like this.

Comment: If you declare an array as a local non-static variable, or as a class member that you don't explicitly initialize, it will be uninitialized. All elements will have an *indeterminate* value. For example, in your `main` function the `list` array will be uninitialized, attempting to use any element in the array before they are initialized will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply resize a statically allocated array so you'll want to either use **std::vector** or **malloc/new** to allocate a dynamic array. However in that case you can't determine the size of the array using **sizeof()**. So you either keep a size variable or use a "delimiter" value in order to pinpoint the end of the array.